# Problems with field names and appending files in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

Okay, so I have nearly 200 tables in an Access database. The tables are of plant species abundance data, and I would like to combine them into a master data file. Each table contains basically the same columns of species; however, many are spelled slightly differently.

When I run an SQL query in MS Access it won't let me append the tables with each other because  of the field names being spelled just a little different.

Any thoughts that would help?

The query I am running is an append query:

```
INSERT INTO masterTable SELECT * FROM siteTable
```

and, as an example, the differences in field names are pretty minor
(e.g. "Spp.A" vs "SppA" or "SpeciesOne" vs "Species1")

Thanks for any help,
Paul

Comment: You shall first uniformize all table field names... It's better manually.

Comment: Really? Do you mean better in terms of control or better in terms of effort? You're saying that I should go into each table and change each field name manually?

Comment: Or INSERT INTO masterTable (y1, y2, y3)
SELECT x1,x2,x3 FROM siteTable; for all siteTables, each time with different x1,x2,x3: the same quantity of work? It'll be simpler if your sitetables have same number of fields in the same order, even not with the same names.

Comment: I think that would be even more work. The names of these fields are unfortunately lengthy. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use vba for this, you'll also need to change the column names I'm using in the masterTable, which in my example are just column1, column2 & column3, and to set the maximum column index in a couple of places (I've stuck some comments in, so you can see what needs to be changed).

If you dont usually use vba, Create a form with a button, and a click event for the button & put this code in it, then open the form and click the button.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim tdf As TableDef
Dim ii As Long
dim sql as String

Set db = CurrentDb()
docmd.setwarnings false

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    'change column list as required:
    sql = "INSERT INTO masterTable (Column1, Column2, Column3) SELECT "
    'change 2 to maximum column number - 1:
    for ii = 0 to 2
        sql = sql & tdf.Fields(ii).Name
        'change 2 to maximum column number - 1 again:
        if ii < 2 then
            sql = sql & ","
        end if
    next
    sql = sql & ")"

    docmd.runsql sql
Next
docmd.setwarnings true
```

This should work I think. (I'm hoping there's no syntax errors, as I havent tested it, but the logic isnt exactly rocket science)

Hope this helps